# Java 8 Repeatable annotation

Tags: java, annotations, java-8

Trying to figure out how to get along with Java 8 Repeatable annotations support.

Following :
https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/03/java-8-repeating-annotation-explained-in-5-minutes/

it works flawlessly.

But if I'm modifying the example and add just a @Manufacturer on the Car class I'm unable to read that single annotation. So if there's only 1 occurrence of the repeated annotation it can't be read.

So having:

```
@Manufacturer("Range Rover")
public class Car {

}


Manufacturer[] a = Car.class.getAnnotationsByType(Manufacturer.class );
```

the size here will be 0

and

```
Cars cars = Car.class.getAnnotation(Cars.class);
for(Manufacturer car: cars.value())
System.out.println(car.value());
```

here there will be a NPE on the cars..

Why's that ?

Comment: To access an annotation via reflection, it has to be marked as `@Retention(RUNTIME)`. Does your Cars annotation have this?

Comment: yes sure, that doesn't sound to be the problem, it works if I'm annotating the class with multiple annotations, but if there's only one I'm not able to get it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that the `Manufacturer` annotation doesn't have a `RetentionPolicy` declared only the container annotation (`Cars`).

So adding

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```

also on the `Manufacturer` annotation will read the annotation in a *container based* /*single based* manner (in a manner of speaking)

Thanks Sean, at least you answer gave me a clue...

Comment: You are mixing up the type names. `Car` is not an annotation. Obviously, it isn’t a good idea to name the container annotation holding multiple `Manufacturer` annotations “`Cars`”…

Comment: Never mind. You can edit your answer. Besides that, maybe you should leave a comment at the blog about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You try to get an annotation of type Cars and not of type Manufacturer.

The following solution worked:

```
    Manufacturer[] annotations = Car.class.getAnnotationsByType(Manufacturer.class);
    for (Manufacturer annotation : annotations) {
        System.out.println(annotation.name());
    }
```

You should always pass the type of the annotation to getAnnotation or getAnnotationsByType and not the type of the class itself.

Hope it helpt you

Comment: Manufacturer[] a = Car.class.getAnnotationsByType(Manufacturer.class ); that is what I'm doing (as specified in the example link). The problem is that if the Car class has 2 @Manufacturer annotation I'm able to read them, if there's only one I'm not. Am I missing something ??

Comment: See the tutorial in the original question. You can read them in 2 ways, in the original post I just explained the outputs of them..Sorry if this was a bit confusing...